# How do I make a movie for upload to YouTube from a series of PNG images on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video

Does anyone know how to make a movie (avi / mpg) thats uploadable to YouTube from a series of PNG images? Also, how would I add a .caf audio file to that videostream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of libraries like x264 to do this type of thing for you, but you'll probably need to use a library. Video encoding is not an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do it with ImageMagick which has been [ported to the iPhone](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14089)  Try the 'convert' command.  (I haven't done this myself, so you might need to do some research on the latest iPhone port and how to use the command.)

Comment: thanks but i like to make it myself programmaticly from within my app :) just some images to avi