# How would I convert a series of JPEG images to an uncompressed AVI on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, jpeg

I'm trying to convert a series of JPEG images into a simple uncompressed AVI movie.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: The answers to your previous question appear to address this case, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396834/how-do-i-make-a-movie-for-upload-to-youtube-from-a-series-of-png-images-on-the-ip

Comment: Hi Christian are able to accomplish above task, can you update me if it can be achieved using iphone sdk 4.1.

Comment: i have no idea... i am still looking for a working source example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the ported ffmpeg-version you can use on the iPhone, they provide exactly what you need :)!

Comment: any link? also i heared there could be some licence problems (I would have to make my app open source!)

Comment: oh, I'm not sure about any licensing problem. However I think you don't need to open your app's source, just give them the credits at your About-page. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/CreatingaQTKitStoporStillMotionApplication/CreatingaQTKitStoporStillMotionApplication.html

Comment: This is Mac, the iPhone-frameworks doesn't contain a QTKit-framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you must convert it to an avi file Petteri Hietavirta's answer might really help. But if you just want to show the video with those images in your app, you might as well use a timer with a very small interval and animate all the images. It looks as smooth as a video.

P.S. - UIImageView provides inbuilt animation but it requires creating an array of all the images, which is not recommended for a large number of images, as it eats up lot of memory.

Comment: i need to save and upload later